# How to dynamically load XAML for getting Controls information

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, system.reflection, xamlparseexception

I am trying to load a Silverlight project to read every `XAML` file by creating an instance using reflection, `Activator.CreateInstance`, of every `XAML` class for reading its controls.

**C# Code:**

```
string strPath = "SilverlightUI.dll";
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(strPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
Assembly assembly = assemblyPart.Load(sri.Stream);
Type[] typeArray = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

foreach (Type type in typeArray)
{
    object ctl = (object)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    // Following exception is occurring while creating an instance using above line of code 
    // Exception "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ComboBoxStyle"
}
```

Perhaps, reflection is not able to recognize Silverlight style `ComboBoxStyle`. How can i possibly create an instance to read every control in the XAML file dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find the required solution to my problem after struggling with the Google.

1. *Copy* all the *Style Resources* from *Silverlight* project (intended to load).
2. *Paste* them in the `App.xaml` of the Master/Caller *Silverlight* project or application, which is using the reflection code to load the Silverlight Controls information

Following these steps will eliminate the ***XAML Parse Exception*** of missing *Style*.

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ComboBoxStyle

Reference: [XAML Parser cannot find resource within dynamically loaded XAP when creating form instance](http://www.techques.com/question/1-2810018/XAML-Parser-cannot-find-resource-within-dynamically-loaded-XAP-when-creating-form-instance)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to load custom controls using the `XamlReader` class.
I am using plain string that contains the XAML of the control not like your reflection idea.

```
//string xaml = "<...>";
var content = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as FrameworkElement;
this.scrollViewer.Content = content;
```

The type `XamlReader` is in `System.Windows.Markup`.

If it is possible in your case you can try to get XAML resources from your assembly and read them to string. Then use the provided code. After you have the `content` variable you can do anything using the Silverlight API to the control.
Hope this will help you.